# Multi-level inheritance in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first

Hierarchy:

- abstract Package
- ServerPackage: Package
- ClientPackage: ServerPackage

In terms of EF CF, all three tables have a one-to-one relationship. Have I selected the right composition to cater to the following scenario?

Scenario:

- Abstract Package is created by the server upon request with unique Guid.
- Server creates ServerPackage and sends to client.
- Client processes ServerPackage and creates a ClientPackage to send back to server.

In other words, as soon as a Package request comes in, a ServerPackage AND a ClientPackage should be created. I am assuming this will not work since I need both packages to be tied to the same abstract Package Id.

Should I be using composition instead of inheritance and force a one-to-one relationship?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work only if all your packages are same instance => when the server receives request it must immediately create `ClientPackage`. It cannot create `Package` because `Package` is abstract and if it only creates `ServerPackage` you will not be able to create `ClientPackage` with the same Id. So it looks like whole your inheritance will be redundant in such scenario.

If you want to follow your workflow you need composition.

Comment: What structure would you suggest? I thought of deriving both from Package and making the server and client have a one-to-one foreign key with the top level table rather then the base class. But that seems unnatural. How would you handle this?

Comment: Once you find one to one relationship in the database you should always ask yourselves: do I really need it? There are scenarios when this relation is useful but in most cases it is just overhead. I would probably use just single table / entity because from your description I don't see any reason to split it.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping you would say something like that. It sounds very logical from a DB perspective but not from a class design one. Is there a way I can keep my class hierarchy and still package the table as you suggest?